# How to Calculate Expected Value While Accounting for Historical Skill Level

Tags: expected-value

Let's say there is a skill based contest that has 1,000 people competing in it.  No one player can manipulate another players outcome.  You competed in this contest type 10,000 times and your historical average is that you finish in the top 40%.

How would you calculate the "expected value" of competing in this contest if the parameters were as follows:

1st through 300th place receive a prize amount of \$10.  The cost to enter the contest is $5.

I know the way to calculate the expected value **without** taking into account the fact that you historically finish in the top 40% would be: (30% chance of winning X \$10 prize) + (70% chance of losing X -\$5 loss) = -$0.05 expected value

**However**, how do you calculate the expected value of this contest when taking into account that you historically finish in the top 40% because of your skill level?

Comment: Isn't the without-expectation $30\%\cdot\,\$10+100\%\cdot\,-\$5=-\$2$, since you always pay $\$5$ to participate?

Answer (score 0):

I'd reason that the skill is normally distributed among participants. And apparently, I am in the upper tail, making up 40%.

So after the contest is over, then I'd expect my results to be among the 400 best.

The question is then, what is the probability of being among the 300 best?

Without any more information, I'd estimate that probability at a fair 75%.

Therefore I'd calculate the expected winnings as $75\%\cdot\,\$10+100\%\cdot\,-\$5=\$2,50$.